# Google Sheets: How to Find the Least Popular/Common Value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for help finding a function/formula to find the least common value in a col on Google Sheets.

In a couple of words, the opposite of the Mode function.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the range you want to count is A2:A40, try:

```
=unique(filter(A2:A40,countif(A2:A40, A2:A40)=MIN(countif(A2:A40,A2:A40))))
```

Comment: tried and works fine, cheers JPV.  Takes a while to load so might prefer adding a unique() list and index,matching the min value.

Comment: I don't think that this works any more - at least, it doesn't appear to with non-numeric data.